# Run bash "find" command in variable

Tags: bash, find, quoting

```
# Let's have a few test files
$ touch alpha beta
$ find ./*
./alpha
./beta

# Try find with filtering
$ find ./* -not -path './beta'
./alpha

# Now again, but save the command in a variable
$ F="find ./* -not -path './beta'"
$ echo "$F"
find ./* -not -path './beta'
$ $F
./alpha
./beta
```

Why did this happen? Something about quoting...?

Comment: how about `F='find ./* -not -path "./beta"'`? btw backticks are discouraged.

Comment: This has the same result. `F='find ./* -not -path ./beta'` (without quotes) works correctly. However in my real case I would like to keep quotes somehow, because of a `*` in the filter.

Comment: *Don't* store the command in a variable; define a function instead.